# Reducing link clickable width

Tags: html, href

I have a link on my website and I dont like the way it is clickable along the whole width of the page.
I have tried putting blank divs with width attributes on either side of the link and tried putting a width attribute in the link itself. I also tried the overflow attribute recommended in another answer.
Does anyone have any suggestions? Here is the code:

```
<div align= 'center'>
<a href = "link"><p style="font-size: 15px;">text</p></a>
</div>
```

Comment: switch the `<p>` and `<a>` tag around. now the `a`-element is around the `p`-element which takes up the full width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` stands for a paragraph, which is a block level element. These use the full width available to them by default. Your case looks like you want a `span` instead, which is an inline element, like the link itself, that only spans the contained text.

```
<div align= "center">
<a href = "link"><span style="font-size: 15px;">text</span></a>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could skip the tag completely by applying the style directly to the link instead.

```
<div align= "center">
<a href = "link" style="font-size: 15px;">text</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this:

```
<div align= 'center'>
<p style="font-size: 15px;"><a href="link">text</a></p>
</div>
```